# slurm didn't execute my Python code after running a few lines but also didn't stop, whereas it worked well on my local Linux

Tags: python, linux, nlp, slurm

**my code:**

```
from datasets import load_dataset
MAX_LEN = 512
dataset = load_dataset("glue","mrpc")
from transformers import AutoTokenizer
from transformers import RobertaTokenizerFast

#tokenizer =AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")
tokenizer = RobertaTokenizerFast.from_pretrained("/data/home//raw_roberta/Roberta_Tokenizer", max_length=MAX_LEN, padding='max_length', return_tensors='pt')

print("mapped_dataset")

mapped_dataset = dataset.map(lambda x: tokenizer(x["sentence1"], x["sentence2"], max_length = MAX_LEN, truncation=True, padding='max_length', return_tensors='pt'), batched=True)

print("completeed mapped_dataset")

from transformers import DataCollatorWithPadding
data_collator= DataCollatorWithPadding(tokenizer=tokenizer)

from transformers import AutoModelForSequenceClassification
from transformers import RobertaForMaskedLM

#model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased",num_labels = 2)
#model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("data/home//raw_roberta/Roberta_Model/checkpoint-90000", num_labels = 2)
#model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("data/home//raw_roberta/Roberta_Model/checkpoint-90000")
base_model = RobertaForMaskedLM.from_pretrained('/data/home//raw_roberta/Roberta_Model/checkpoint-90000').roberta

from transformers import TrainingArguments
print(base_model.config)
```

**I run above code on my local linux,it only takes about 2 minutes to execute.the log:**

The tokenizer class you load from this checkpoint is not the same type as the class this function is called from. It may result in unexpected tokenization.
The tokenizer class you load from this checkpoint is 'BertTokenizer'.
The class this function is called from is 'RobertaTokenizer'.
Special tokens have been added in the vocabulary, make sure the associated word embeddings are fine-tuned or trained.
The tokenizer class you load from this checkpoint is not the same type as the class this function is called from. It may result in unexpected tokenization.
The tokenizer class you load from this checkpoint is 'BertTokenizer'.
The class this function is called from is 'RobertaTokenizerFast'.
Special tokens have been added in the vocabulary, make sure the associated word embeddings are fine-tuned or trained.

```
mapped_dataset
completeed mapped_dataset
RobertaConfig {
  "_name_or_path": "/data/home//raw_roberta/Roberta_Model/checkpoint-90000",
  "architectures": [
    "RobertaForMaskedLM"
  ],
  "attention_probs_dropout_prob": 0.1,
  "bos_token_id": 0,
  "classifier_dropout": null,
  "eos_token_id": 2,
  "hidden_act": "gelu",
  "hidden_dropout_prob": 0.1,
  "hidden_size": 768,
  "initializer_range": 0.02,
  "intermediate_size": 3072,
  "layer_norm_eps": 1e-12,
  "max_position_embeddings": 514,
  "model_type": "roberta",
  "num_attention_heads": 12,
  "num_hidden_layers": 12,
  "pad_token_id": 1,
  "position_embedding_type": "absolute",
  "torch_dtype": "float32",
  "transformers_version": "4.33.2",
  "type_vocab_size": 1,
  "use_cache": true,
  "vocab_size": 52000
}
```

**but when I upload my code to slurm, it run for 4 hours,only get these log:**

```
/data/home//anaconda3/envs/py38v1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/__init__.py:138: UserWarning: A NumPy version >=1.16.5 and <1.23.0 is required for this version of SciPy (detected version 1.24.4)
  warnings.warn(f"A NumPy version >={np_minversion} and <{np_maxversion} is required for this version of "
The tokenizer class you load from this checkpoint is not the same type as the class this function is called from. It may result in unexpected tokenization. 
The tokenizer class you load from this checkpoint is 'BertTokenizer'. 
The class this function is called from is 'RobertaTokenizer'.
Special tokens have been added in the vocabulary, make sure the associated word embeddings are fine-tuned or trained.
The tokenizer class you load from this checkpoint is not the same type as the class this function is called from. It may result in unexpected tokenization. 
The tokenizer class you load from this checkpoint is 'BertTokenizer'. 
The class this function is called from is 'RobertaTokenizerFast'.
Special tokens have been added in the vocabulary, make sure the associated word embeddings are fine-tuned or trained.
slurmstepd: error: *** JOB xxxxx ON compute-9-0 CANCELLED AT 2024-02-05T08:35:30 DUE TO TIME LIMIT ***
```

**this problem truly confuses me,anyone know how to fix it? thanks!**

Comment: Please improve the format for your code.

Answer (score 0):

check the `python`, `scipy` and `numpy` versions on the local workstation and the computing node(s) on the cluster. If you can create `conda` envs on the cluster, create a `conda` environment with just the `python` + relevant libs. First on the local workstation to check that it works, then replicate it on HPC.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! I tried adding 'flush=True' in print() and it worked.